# Imagem com HOVER responsivo

Tags: html, css

Boa noite, meu nome é Rui.

Estou desenvolvendo meu primeiro site e estou com duvida em relação a imagens usando hover responsivo.

Fiz um hover usando uma imagem preta e branco e colorida, mas só ficou responsivo em tela de PC, celular nao :(

o site é http://www.5kleague.com.br/times.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de ter consertado o bootstrap faça o seguinte, sempre defina um tamanho para as coisas

em todos os seus  coloque uma classe no exemplo vou colocar "time-link" observação, só coloque nas figures que irão ficar as imagens dos times exemplo:

```
<section id="times1">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                    <figure class="time-link">
                        <a  href="perfilTime.html">
                            <img class="cores" src="image/alligators_png.png">
                            <img class="preto" src="image/alligators_png2.png">
                        </a>    
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                    <figure class="time-link">
                        <!--<a href="#">9-->
                            <img class="cores" src="image/biters_png.png">
                            <img class="preto" src="image/biters_png2.png">
                        <!--</a>--> 
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                    <figure class="time-link">
                        <!--<a href="#">-->
                            <img class="cores" src="image/deserts_png.png">
                            <img class="preto" src="image/deserts_png2.png">
                        <!--</a>-->
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                    <figure class="time-link">
                        <!--<a href="#">-->
                            <img class="cores" src="image/drakos_png.png">
                            <img class="preto" src="image/drakos_png2.png">
                        <!--</a>-->
                    </figure>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Depois de colocar time-link nas figures defina um tamanho no seu css, como o tamanho das imagens estão 170 x 150 vou definir assim, coloque margin: 0 auto; para ele centralizar

```
.time-link{
   width: 170px;
   height: 150px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

se quiser diminua a margem do time2 e time3 (OPCIONAL)

```
#time2,#time3{
  margin-top: 5%;
}
```

Fazendo isso funcionará, qualquer coisa grita

Comment: Oi Anderson, obrigado pela resposta !!! Fiz tudo que você disse relacionado ao JQuery, mesmo assim não funcionou. Estudei mais um pouco sobre as grid do bootstrap e nada ... 

Coloquei col-xs-12 para mostrar apenas 1 time em mobile e col-md-3 para uma row com 4 times, correto ?

Sera que meu css esta errado, pode me ajudar por favor?

Comment: Fez? O site ainda está sem a pasta js e sem o jquery

Comment: ah sim, é porque eu testei aqui em casa mesmo, mas vou hospedar a pasta no filezilla cmo o arquivo.. pronto ! rsrs

Comment: Ok irmãozin @ruiqueiroz Vou alterar a resposta, agora vai funcionar

Comment: Anderson obrigado !!! Consegui, deu tudo certo e estou muito feliz !!! esse site  é importante pra mim, obrigado de verdade. estou impressionado com a boa vontade e ajudar!!!

Comment: que nada amigo se possivel por favor marque a resposta como correta e avalie obrigado @ruiqueiroz